# Travelling with Qatar Airways from Manchester, UK to Delhi, India with a connecting flight at Doha

Tags: air-travel, uk, safety, qatar-airways

The journey from Manchester to Doha involves flying over Libya and Egypt but not the Sinai Peninsula, also the flight flies over Paris.

Is this safe?

Is Qatar airways taking a safe route or should I fly with a different airline like Etihad?

The news about Egypt and Emirates and unsafe zones such as Libya and just the recent news has got me nervous.

I have flown with Qatar before and the flight was very smooth, thank God.

EDIT: I am mostly worried about flying over or skirting over Libya, Egypt, Iran, Iraq and Syria because of recent news and because these are so called terrorist zones.

I had checked the route of the flight by using the routemap on Qatar Airways website and it should skirt over Libya and Egypt.

Comment: What is safe and what is not, at the end of the day, is opinion based. There's a spectrum here roughly between living inside a nuclear shelter and never setting foot outside and going on an aerial sightseeing tour over Aleppo.

Comment: Airline route maps are like subway maps, they're simplified to be easy to understand. The maps I link in my answer are the actual flight routes.

Answer (score 6):

**It's perfectly safe**.  Qatar Airways flights from Manchester to Doha actually do *not* pass over Libya or Egypt, but skirt east of Syria and Iraq by flying over Iran: 
https://flightaware.com/live/flight/QTR22/history/20160801/0800Z/EGCC/OTHH

This is precisely the same route as that flown by Etihad's Manchester flights:
https://flightaware.com/live/flight/ETD16/history/20160801/0810Z/EGCC/OMAA

I'm also not sure why you're worried about Paris, it requires *very* heavy weaponry to hit an airliner flying 10 km overhead.

Comment: ..not just weaponry - you need sophisticated radar systems as well and it was confirmed that no terrorist organizations in those areas (definitely not in France) has that kind of weaponry.